# Calculating the percentage of a slider

Tags: php, jquery, math

Say i have a slider with the Minimum value of -1, and the maximum value of 1. If the user puts the slider handle in the middle, then we would have a value of 0. I just don't know how to calculate that into the 50% of -1 to 1

I then need to do the same thing i reverse, first get the percentage of the slider (say it's 50%). I now need to calculate how much 50% is of -255 to 255 (which should return 0). I've been stuck with this one for a while now, and would appreciate any help i could get.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have two scales, one going from 0 to 100, the other going from -255 to 255. The formula to go from one to the other is quite simple :

- progress = (position - min)/range
- new_pos = new_min + new_range * progress

Note that a percentage already represents this "progress" value, as 20% = (20 - 0)/100. Also note that the range can be defined as max - min.

So assuming you go from -255 to 255 included, that's 511 discrete values (counting the 0, assuming you use int's), and assuming percentage is a value between 0 and 100 (as opposed to between 0 and 1) :

- from percentage to pixels : -255 + 511 * percentage / 100
- from pixels to percentage : 0 + 100 * (pixel + 255) / 511

The same goes for your scale from -1 to 1, which I guess uses continuous values, thus has a range the size of the interval [-1, 1], i.e. min = -1 and range = 2

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
function percentage($slider){
 return ($slider + 1) * 50;
}

function slider($percentage){
return ($percentage/100) * 510 - 255;
}
```